# Need to unzip multiple .zip files (All zip files on app directory)

Tags: c#, zip

My code is unzip only one file need to change it for unzip all files on directory.

```
 using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(file)) //Want to change "file" with directory (for unzip all zip files on that directory)
                {
                    foreach (ZipEntry zipFiles in zip)
                    {
                        zipFiles.Extract(currentpath, true); //Also need overwrite silenthly
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will let you enumerate all zip files from the directory and even in parallel:

```
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles("<directory path>", "*.zip")) 
{
    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(file)) //Want to change "file" with directory (for unzip all zip files on that directory)
    {
        foreach (ZipEntry zipFiles in zip)
        {
            zipFiles.Extract(currentpath, true); //Also need overwrite silenthly
        }
    }
}
```

you can convert it to simply foreach if need to.

Comment: That must be because of you Zip utility. You can simply convert it to foreach. I have updated the code.

Comment: @vendettamit, what library you are using. My syntax throw error for  ZipFile.Read